# Why is this handled exception causing a Force Close? [GeoCoder]

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask, google-geocoder

I have the following in my AsyncTask:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Context... c) {

    try {
        context = c[0];

        myLocation = new Geocoder((Activity)context, Locale.getDefault()); 

        if(myLocation.isPresent())
            myList = myLocation.getFromLocation(LocationHandler.getLat(), LocationHandler.getLon(), 1);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

If I run this AsyncTask with no network connection, my application will Force Close with the following stack output:

```
 java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response from server
 at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
 at com.soyo.winnipegtransit.location.UpdateGeoCoderName.doInBackground(UpdateGeoCoderName.java:44)
 at com.soyo.winnipegtransit.location.UpdateGeoCoderName.doInBackground(UpdateGeoCoderName.java:1)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I'm not sure why this exception is going unhandled?

Comment: For starters, your code shouldn't compile.  You can't `return null` from a method with `void` return type...

Comment: @Chris Actually it compiles fine. It is returning type `Void` not `void`. It will not compile without a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with exceptions not being handled. It usually got solved by just handling the exception with one catch statement, don't ask me how but I'm sure there's a good reason behind this. Have you tried removing the `catch(IOException e)` and just keeping `catch(Exception e)`?

Ryan

Comment: Hey Ryan! Thanks for the suggestion, well it looks like the exception was being handled after all, but I was calling a new AsyncTask in the `onPostExecute()` and that was causing the ForceClose. I'll will post the solution when it allows me.

Comment: Good to hear, removing the other catch statement wouldn't have made a big difference but sometimes you gotta try everything **:D**